# Linkage in Flash CC for HTML canvas project

Tags: html, flash, canvas, base-class, linkage

I got a custom class that I need to assign as Base Class for some symbols on the stage. I tried to use linkage option in Flash, but everything is grayed out. I saw on Adobe's site that linkage for html canvas is currently not supported. 
Is there any other way I can achieve this?